# What does this matrix operation mean?

Tags: matrices, notation

If T is matrix what is this operation? What's name of operation?
[image]

Comment: It probably means the inverse of the transpose but perhaps someone else can comment on this matter.

Comment: It’s certainly an unfortunate notation for “T transpose inverse”. In TeX, it would be better as $T^{-\top}$ (that is, with “top” rather than “T”), even if combining transpose with inverse, which is perhaps dangerous.

Answer (score 2):

Found it! http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transpose
'properties' section, point no.8:
[image]